# Hide data, process to new div with each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

I have multiple same class divs that produce an array and a script that puts them into lists.
I would like to hide a JSON array object from briefly flashing (unprocessed) on the page before the script can process it into lists.

So I put them into a hidden div and the each function stops working.

The .hid divs actually contain:
`<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','lists')%>` that produce the JSON array.

```
<div class="hid" style="display:none;">[{"k":"Model","v":"AB"},{"k":"Color","v":"green"}]</div>
<div class="overview"></div>
<div class="hid" style="display:none;">[{"k":"Model","v":"AC"},{"k":"Color","v":"blue"}]</div>
<div class="overview"></div>
<div class="hid" style="display:none;">[{"k":"Model","v":"AD"},{"k":"Color","v":"red"}]</div>
<div class="overview"></div>
```

My script

```
jQuery('.hid').each(function () {
   var $data = jQuery(this), spec,
       specs = jQuery.parseJSON($data.html());
   jQuery(".overview").html('<div class="bullet_spec"></div>');
   jQuery.each(specs, function () {
       jQuery(".overview").children('div').append('<div class="specs"><span class="label">' + this.k + ':</span><span class="value"> ' + this.v + '</span></div>');
   });
   { 
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qta2p/

Comment: Why parse JSON from HTML content? Seems an unusual way to print JSON, even `data` attributes would be better suited, but passing it directly to your javascript is even better.

Comment: Do you want  `$data.next()` instead of all `$(".overview")`?

Comment: Yes, that really worked! I'm not sure I understand why though. Thanks.